# "NAND only" vs "AND and NOT only" difference?

Tags: boolean, logic, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

When you simplify something down into these two, is there really any difference between?

For example:

```
( (B'C)' * (B'D')' )'
```

Is this and NAND only? If so, can it be converted to AND and NOT only? Or vice-versa? I'm confused on the difference between the two.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  `NAND(x, y)` is exactly equivalent to `NOT(AND(x, y))` (by definition), but it's unclear how that relates to the example in your question.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Is there a symbol for NAND or is it just (AB)'  ?

Comment: Depends on your notation system.  See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke

Answer (score 2):

Your formula:

```
( (B'C)' * (B'D')' )'
```

Assume `'` is negation and `*` and juxtaposition are used for conjunction; disjunction is not shown but would be denoted `+`. Let us rewrite the formula using `not` and `and` instead:

```
not (not (not B and C) and not (not B and not D))
```

Let us also indicate which `not`s go with which `and`s:

```
not (not (not B and C) and not (not B and not D))
^1   ^2         ^2     ^1  ^3         ^3
```

We can therefore eliminate three `not`s and replace the corresponding `and`s with three `nand`s:

```
(not B nand C) nand (not B nand not D)
```

We see right away that the original formula was not expressed using only `nand`s since eliminating pairs of `not`s and `and`s using the definition of `nand` did not eliminate non-`nand` operators.

However, the original formula does consist only of `and` and `not`. Because any formula can be written using `nand`s only, this one can. The lazy way is to just use `not x = x nand x` three times to remove each of the remaining `not`s.